# Xcode 1.3 ,I use first instead any object.Cannot invoke>

Tags: xcode, swift

Cannot invoke 'locationInView' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject!)'

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

```
var newPoint = touches.first.locationInView(self.drawView)
  lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint! , color :drawColor))
lastPoint = newPoint

self.setNeedsDisplay()

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нужно привести тип, по умолчанию в `Set` лежат объекты `NSObject`:

```
if let newPoint = (touches.first as? UITouch)?.locationInView(self.drawView) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: '_??' is not convertible to 'CGPoint' и '<<error type>>?' is not convertible to 'CGPoint'